# How to type Katakana with Google Transliterate?

Tags: localization, google-input-tools

[Google transliterate](http://www.google.co.jp/transliterate/japanese) is a useful tool for typing foreign characters.

However I have some problems when trying to use it to type in Japanese characters. It doesn't seem to offer anyway of inputting katakana characters. Does anyone know how to force Google Transliterate to type in katakana instead of hiragana?

Answer (score 1):

The link on the question now redirects to Google Input Tools. The list of supported languages is on https://www.google.com/intl/en/inputtools/help/languages.html. For Japanese it indicates that offers Input Method Entry (IME) and Handwriting.

Related

- From Android Enthusiasts : [Inputting katakana on Google Japanese Input](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131527/71386)